# Webapp that speaks out (or shows the pronunciation) of a Korean sentence

Tags: web-apps, audio, educational, language

I have started learning how to pronounce Korean, but I am still not confident.

Is there a website where I could paste a sentence like `나는 생각한다, 고로 나는 존재한다.` and have either spoken out loud, or at least the pronunciation transliterated.

It does not have to be perfect, it could be a basic character-per-character transliteration.

Comment: Could this question use [tag:educational] (used by 16 questions so far) instead of [tag:study] (only used on this question), or should they have a different meaning?

Comment: I'd suggest that educational and study are synonyms in this context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good old [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/):
Click on the speaker icon in the bottom-right of the text box.

For the above phrase (naneun saeng-gaghanda, golo naneun jonjaehanda): [Click on the speaker icon](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%EB%82%98%EB%8A%94%20%EC%83%9D%EA%B0%81%ED%95%9C%EB%8B%A4%2C%20%EA%B3%A0%EB%A1%9C%20%EB%82%98%EB%8A%94%20%EC%A1%B4%EC%9E%AC%ED%95%9C%EB%8B%A4.)

Keep an eye on [Ivona text-to-speech](http://www.ivona.com/) too. They're making some unbelievably realistic voices, and though I don't know of a Korean voice yet, who knows what the future will bring once the east opens up.